# React's new JSX runtime is making my bundle size larger?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

According to React's blog (https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html), there's a new JSX runtime for Babel:

> Depending on your setup, its compiled output may slightly improve the
> bundle size.

However, it made my bundle size 2% bigger. I was curious, so I dug into the output. The dev version looks like this:

```
(0,react_jsx_dev_runtime__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.jsxDEV)("div", {})
```

And the production version looks like this:

```
(0,a.jsx)("div",{})
```

In the React blog's example, they have `_jsx` as a function instead of a method. This is probably contributing to the 2% file size increase. Is this a Webpack issue? Is it possible to make Webpack optimize this further?

What other reasons could there be for the new runtime making the bundle larger?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Here's a gist with a larger example to compare the difference between the old and new JSX transforms: https://gist.github.com/OliverJAsh/51b2138922a93a7f7d8ed53701ce9afe. I asked on Twitter: https://twitter.com/OliverJAsh/status/1481912497175203840 — maybe someone will reply there